# Django 'Undefined' object has no attribute id when when working with legacy database

Tags: python, django, mako

I have a django application that I'm trying to use with a legacy database.

Whenever I try to pull down any data, I get this error:

`'Undefined' object has no attribute 'id'`

This happens no matter what attribute I give it.

I made sure that everything in the database is migrated with `./manage.py showmigrations`.

Here is my view:

```
from django_mako_plus import view_function
from django.conf import settings
from homepage.models import Users, MyTable

@view_function
def process_request():
    u = MyTable.objects.get(id=1)
    # print("User object: " + str(u.id))
    context = {
        'u':u,
    }
    # django mako plus changes the way you render a template
    return request.dmp.render('test-delete.html', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
<%inherit file="base.htm"/>
<%block name="header">
</%block>
<%block name="content">
    <!-- DMP Changes the syntax here too. Default django is {{u.id}} but dmp is {u.id} -->
    ${u.id}
</%block>
```

Here are my models:

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    p_number = models.TextField(db_column='P NUMBER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_table'
```

My models were generated with `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

I assume that the error is occuring because django is failing to retrieve the MyTable object, so how can I get django to fetch it and display the data?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using that template library. And no, if it couldn't retrieve the object, you would get a `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using the templating library because it makes life for other members of my team easier.  What is the `Undefined` exception then?  Is it not saving the object to my variable?

Comment: This is most likely a mako issue. Read carefully through http://django-mako-plus.readthedocs.io, and also examine the really useful debug output which DMP generates.